# Magento 1.9 : Create a CSV of product SKU, Quantity and Price

Tags: magento-1, csv, export

I'm trying to work out how to create a downloadable CSV file that contains fields for Product SKU, Quantity (should be set to 5 if more than 5 in stock) and Price in Magento 1.x. Price in this instance is in a custom attribute called ChannelPrice and not the Magento attribute Price. This CSV will be produced every 5 minutes or so using a Cron.
I'm not a PHP wizard unfortunately, so I am not sure where to start here - be it via some sort of API, or directly via the database. Any things I need to consider or help will be most gratefully received!
Many thanks in advance.
Andrew

Comment: Please specify magento version?

Comment: Currently it is 1.9.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should set you on the right path. You'll need to adjust the collection to get products with a quantity of more than 5 though.
Save this as a php file and then call it with a cron job every 5 minutes.

```
<?php
// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.csv');
// Load the Magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
$store_id = '1';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store_id);

//Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);

// output the column headings
echo "'sku', 'price', 'stock'";
echo "\n";

// Load the product collection
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','price'))
->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
        'left'
    );
//$products ->getSelect()->limit(20);

foreach ($products as $product) {
        $sku=$product->getSku();
        //$price=Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(), true, false), //." ".$currencyCode;
    $price = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getPrice(), true)*1.2;
    $qty=$product->getQty();
    echo $sku . ",";
    echo $price . ",";
    echo $qty . "\n";
    $sku='';
    $price='';
    $qty='';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've had a play around with the code and got everything working how I would like apart from one aspect.

I want to be able to get the value of a custom attribute storing a price rather than the Magento default price attribute. I'm not sure how to go about that as there are no predefined get/set methods for individual custom attributes, unlike the default attributes Magento provides and has get/set methods for. If you had any suggestions on where I need to be looking for this I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Add your attribute label to the `addAttributeToSelect` array and then you should be able to use `$product->getYourAttribute();` where `YourAttribute` is your attribute label.

Comment: That's brilliant - I've got it all working now! Thanks so much for your excellent help, suggestions and script. It is most appreciated :-)